# Page does not load the masterpage in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I'm just starting with asp.net and followed a tutorial on how to make a masterpage, [http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-35-applications/masterpages).
But having followed the tutorial i still couldn't make it work. I even used the same template which is used in the video.

The code i have is auto-generated through the wizards of visual studio.

To be more specific: I dont get any error messages just a plain page with the css which comes from a template i used from the tutorial. The div's with the menu and the rest does not show on screen. (should have written this in the first place)

From the masterpage:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div id="header">
            <p> <a href="#">Link 1</a> . <a href="#">Link 2</a> . <a href="#">Link 3</a> . <a href="#">Link 4</a></p>
        </div>

        <div id="subheader">
                <p>Apple Core 1.0</p>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
                <p><a href="#">Menu 1</a> <a href="#">Menu 2</a> <a href="#">Menu 3</a> <a href="#">Menu 4</a> <a href="#">Menu 5</a> <a href="#">Menu 6 </a></p>
        </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

From default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <br />
<h1>Hey</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Weird enough i seem to be able to get the menu to show up on screen when i completly remove the content tags from the default.aspx

Comment: `Does not work`? Could you be a little more specific? Maybe you are getting an error or something?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to help with the information provided.  You'll have to at least show us _some_ code, preferably the code relevant to the problem.  You'll probably need to do some debugging and tinkering on your end to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: The way I see it, is that there should be no tinkering or debugging to be done. The template works in the video, the code is auto-generated by visual studio. I probably have done something wrong but i just dont see what.

Comment: So how are we supposed to know what you did? At least include the page header and the name of the class from the page code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should try something like this

### your masterpage

```
<div id="header">
    <p> <a href="#">Link 1</a> . <a href="#">Link 2</a> . <a href="#">Link 3</a> . <a href="#">Link 4</a></p>
</div>

<div id="subheader">
    <p>Apple Core 1.0</p>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <p><a href="#">Menu 1</a> <a href="#">Menu 2</a> <a href="#">Menu 3</a> <a href="#">Menu 4</a> <a href="#">Menu 5</a> <a href="#">Menu 6     </a></p>
</div>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**place the menu code outside the content place holder in masterpage

### your aspx page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="WebApplication2.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MenuContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <br />
<h1>Hey</h1>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are doing is *overriding* the MasterPage content by putting HTML inside the `PlaceHolder` tags in both the MasterPage *and* the ContentPage.  This is actually a feature of the MasterPage concept.  If you want something that is standard on your pages, but you want the ability to replace it on certain pages, then you put the content in a PlaceHolder and provide replacement content on the pages that should have something different.  (Alternatively, you could think of this as "use this default content if nothing is provided in the ContentPage.")

Your comment about getting the menu to show up when you remove the content tags is because you've removed the custom tags that are replacing the content from the MasterPage.  If you have some content that you *always* want on *every page* that uses a given MasterPage, put the content in the MasterPage but not inside a PlaceHolder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, should've seen it myself.. although i dont get why the guy in the tutorial seems to do the same thing i did, but his menu seemed to show up.

Comment: I didn't look at the video to see what might have been confusing or misinterpreted.